# why does it return 5 instead of 3 in this code?

Tags: python-3.x, function

Hey guys I have a question regarding the following code: (I use python 3)

```
def foo (x):
   def bar (z, x = 0):
      return z + x
   return bar(3, x)

foo(2)
```

Apparently the return value is `5`. But no matter how I draw the frame, it comes out returning `3` on my paper. Could someone help me out here? Thanks :)

Comment: Are you saying you think it should be 3, but you get 5? 5 is the correct answer, and this works just fine for me. I don't understand what you mean by "draw the frame" either?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you're asking why the program is returning 5 ?

The `bar` definition in `foo` acts exactly as if it were defined outside `foo` function. `x` is shadowed but it acts like it was completely another variable.

So, when you call `foo(2)`, it calls `bar(3, 2)` which returns `3+2` = `5`.

Comment: Thank you Bastien. I was wondering why x  in bar took on the global value of 2 instead of its default argument. - If I understand correctly, default arguments are only triggered when no other values are provided? If any value is assigned by either global frame or parent frame, the default value will be overwritten? Thanks again!

Comment: @mobilevivi Yes ! When you define `bar(z, x=0)`, it means that you can either call `bar` with two arguments (and `x` will have the value of the second argument) or with only one argument (and `x` will have his default value, here `0`).

Comment: Perfection! Thank you so much, Bestien! you the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the code helps understanding it.

`bar(3,x)` returns `3+x` as x is provided (if x were not provided, it would have been `0` by default.

`foo(2)` returns `bar(3,x)` but as x is `2` then you receive `5` as the final response `bar(3,2)`

Comment: Thank you, Pat. I was wondering why x in bar took on the global value of 2 instead of its default argument 0. - If I understand correctly, default arguments are only triggered when no other values are provided? If any value is assigned by either global frame or parent frame, the default value will be overwritten? Thanks again!